# Need to delete a large number of files

Tags: linux

I need to delete a large number of files located in a specific folder (`wc` command is retrieving around `2392934`). The folder contains files of both years 2015 & 2016. I want to only delete files of 2015 and for that I have created this script:

```
echo 'going to given path'
cd /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/xidpe/
pwd
b=$(ls -lrt | grep '2015' | awk '{print $9}')
echo 'listen tail outcome'
echo 'going to del'
rm -rf $b
exit
```

But it returns this error message:

```
./test.sh: line 10: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

I have tried `xargs` also:

```
b=$(ls -lrt | xargs '2016' | awk '{print $9}')
```

But it returns this error message:

```
xargs: 2016: No such file or directory
```

Is there any changes need to be done in my script or any other ways to delete these files (only for year 2015)?

Comment: is the year identified in the file name somehow, or only in the timestamps ?

Answer (score 0):

If the year appears in the filename:

`find /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/xidpe/ -type f -name '*2015*' -delete`

To remove files created before one year before now:

`find /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/xidpe/ -type f -ctime +365 -delete`

Comment: this command is not giving any output. Only showing blank screen after executing this command. Even from root login.

Comment: That is exactly how it works: it removes all files with that pattern and says nothing.

If you want to see the file list in advance, run it first without the "-delete".